# Is there a way of setting line height in Gmail within html email

Tags: html, css, newsletter, electronic-direct-mail

I've coded a HTML email.

I've tried setting line-height inline using pixels and percentages and gmail seems to ignore everything. Is there a way of setting this or will gmail always strip my line-height value?

psuedo-code is:

```
<div>
<span style="line-height: 110%">Text content</span>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Set the line-height in the `<div>`, not the `<span>`. Gmail also seems to ignore it in `<p>` elements.

Answer (score 2):

I always use the style below to fix the line-height in Gmail.

```
<style>
.ExternalClass * {
line-height: 100%;
}  
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using another unit? Maybe `em` or just a multiplier without a unit? `line-height: 2` for example doubles the value of the `font-size`.

Otherwise check http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails for more information about HTML e-mails and post us your complete code.